# Github pages website is on HTTPS but Rest API is on HTTP

Tags: https, github-pages

I have github pages website which makes request to a hosted server which is HTTP and my browser blocks it.

Its assignment for university so I don't really want to pay for HTTPS on the server and I can't use something else for the front-end as I have sent the url to my professor expecting that this is where my web app will be hosted.

Is there anything I can do, which doesn't involve paying that much money?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I encountered this same issue when making API calls.  Here's an easy workaround:

1. Get your api endpoint (for this example, let’s say
   http://api.catphotos.io/)
2. Prepend the CORS API link https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ to
   your link
3. Make sure to leave the http:// on your endpoint.
4. Your new link should look like this:
   https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.catphotos.io/
5. Make your API calls with your new link!

*Source: [johnalcher.me](https://johnalcher.me/blog/bypassing-mixed-content-error-in-github-pages)*

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the GitHub Pages help docs](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/):

> HTTPS enforcement is required for GitHub Pages sites created after June 15, 2016 and using a github.io domain.

That means you can't disable the `https://` redirect. You could [use a custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) which then leaves the `https://` stuff up to you.

Or you could move the stuff from the other server to GitHub Pages, assuming it's not too big.

Comment: The server is NodeJS with MongoDB. As far as I know I can host only front-end projects on Github Pages

Comment: @ЛуциПетков That's correct. So you either have to use a custom domain, or you need to use something other than GitHub pages. Can't you host your frontend on the same server as everything else?